Issues with running PATCH request in an Inertia, Vue 3 and Laravel 11, using Filepond
Firstly, I am using Inertiajs, Vue 3, and Laravel for my application. I have the following form for creating projects and uploading files to the backend. When creating a project (that's through a post request), everything works just fine. As you can see below, I am using the same form for creating and updating a project. The issue happens when I want to update a project.
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Head, Link, useForm } from "@inertiajs/vue3";

import InputError from "@/Components/InputError.vue";

import ContactSelector from "@/Components/Contact/ContactSelector.vue";

import AuthLayout from "@/Layouts/AuthLayout.vue";

import { IconPlus } from "@tabler/icons-vue";

import Spinner from "@/Components/Spinner.vue";

import TextInput from "@/Components/TextInput.vue";

import { UseDark } from "@vueuse/components";

import { DatePicker } from 'v-calendar'

import { ref } from "vue";

import 'v-calendar/style.css'

import { Project } from "@/types";

import Navheader from "@/Components/Backend/Navheader.vue";

import vueFilePond, { setOptions } from "vue-filepond";
import "filepond/dist/filepond.min.css";
import "filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.css";

import FilePondPluginFileValidateType from "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type";
import FilePondPluginFileValidateSize from 'filepond-plugin-file-validate-size';
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from "filepond-plugin-image-preview";

import type { FilePond } from "filepond";
import PreTap from "@/Components/PreTap.vue";

const FilePondInput = vueFilePond(
  FilePondPluginFileValidateType,
  FilePondPluginFileValidateSize,
  FilePondPluginImagePreview
);

const projectGalleryPond = ref<FilePond | null>(null);
const multiFile = ref([]);

const props = defineProps<{
  project: Project;
}>();

const form = useForm({
  name: props.project.name,
  description: props.project.description,
  poster: props.project.poster_url,
  customer_id: props.project?.customer_id,
  production: props.project.production ?? new Date(),
  images: props.project.media
});

const handlePondInit = () => {

  setOptions({
    credits: false,
    server: {
      url: undefined,
      patch: null
    }
  });

  if (props.project.media) {

    multiFile.value = props.project.media.map((image) => ({
      source: image.original_url,

      options: {
        type: 'server',
      },

    })) as any;

  }

}

const handleAddImage = () => {

  const files = projectGalleryPond.value?.getFiles();

  if (files && files.length) {

    form.images = files.map(fileItem => fileItem.file as File) as any;

  } else {

    form.images = []

  }

};

const handleRemoveImage = () => {

  handleAddImage()

};

function onSubmit() {

  form.transform((data) => {

    const formData: Partial<Project> = {
      name: data.name,
      poster_url: data.poster,
      production: data.production,
      customer_id: data.customer_id,
    };

    if (!! data.description) {
      formData.description = data.description
    }

    if (data.images?.length) {
      formData.media = data.images
    }

    return formData;

  })

  if (props.project.pid) {

    form.put(route('auth.projects.update', props.project.pid), {
      preserveScroll: true,

      onSuccess: () => {
        form.reset()
        projectGalleryPond.value?.removeFiles();
      },
    });

    return;

  }

  form.post(route('auth.projects.store'), {
    preserveScroll: true,

    onSuccess: () => {
      form.reset()
      projectGalleryPond.value?.removeFiles();
    },
  });
}

const disabledDates = ref([
  {
    repeat: {
      weekdays: [1, 7],
    },
  },
])

defineOptions({
  layout: AuthLayout,
});
</script>

<template>
    <Head
      :title="props.project.pid ? `Edit ${props.project.name}` : 'New project'"
    />

    <Navheader>

      <nav
        class="flex items-center w-full gap-1 mx-auto dark:text-white dark:border-gray-700"
      >
      <h2 class="text-xl font-semibold dark:text-gray-300 sm:inline-block">
        New project
      </h2>

      <span class="flex-1"></span>

      <button
        type="submit"
        @click.prevent="onSubmit"
        :disabled="form.processing"
        class="inline-flex items-center justify-center gap-2 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-800 bg-white border border-gray-200 shadow-sm -ms-px first:rounded-s-lg first:ms-0 rounded-s-lg rounded-e-lg focus:z-10 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-50 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none dark:bg-neutral-900 dark:border-neutral-700 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-neutral-800 dark:focus:bg-neutral-800">

        <IconPlus stroke="2.5" size="16" />

        <span>
          {{ props.project.pid ? "Update" : "Create" }}
        </span>

        <Spinner v-if="form.processing" />

      </button>

      <Link
        as="button"
        :href="route('auth.projects.index')"
        class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-800 border border-transparent rounded-lg gap-x-2 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-neutral-700 dark:focus:bg-neutral-700">
        Cancel
      </Link>

    </nav>

  </Navheader>

  <article class="sm:px-6 lg:px-8">

    <section class="max-w-2xl px-6 py-12 mx-auto">

      <form>

        <div
          class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 mb-4 sm:gap-8 sm:grid-cols-2">

          <section class="grid col-span-2 gap-8 sm:grid-cols-2">

            <div>
              <label
                for="name"
                class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white"
              >
                Project name
              </label>

              <TextInput
                id="name"
                v-model="form.name"
                placeholder="Type project's name"
                class="w-full"
                type="text"
              />

              <InputError :message="form.errors.name" />
            </div>

            <div>
              <label
                for="company"
                class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                Customer
              </label>

              <ContactSelector
                v-model="form.customer_id"
                placeholder="Pick a project's customer" />

              <InputError :message="form.errors.customer_id" />
            </div>

          </section>

          <div class="col-span-2">
            <label
              class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
              Completion date
            </label>

            <UseDark v-slot="{ isDark }">

              <DatePicker
                v-model="form.production"
                is-required show-weeknumbers
                :disabled-dates="disabledDates"
                :is-dark="isDark"
                title-position="left"
                expanded
                :masks="{
                  input: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
                }" />

            </UseDark>

            <InputError :message="form.errors.production" />
          </div>

          <div class="col-span-2">
            <label
              for="description"
              class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
              Description
            </label>

            <PreTap
              v-model="form.description"
              placeholder="Say a few things worthy noting about the project" />

            <InputError :message="form.errors.description" />
          </div>

          <div class="col-span-2">
            <label
              for="images"
              class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
              Project Images
            </label>

            <FilePondInput
              name="Project Images"
              ref="projectGalleryPond"
              :files="multiFile"
              max-file-size="2MB"
              label-idle="Drop project images here..."
              :allow-multiple="true"
              :allow-mage-preview="true"
              :allow-paste="true"
              :allow-reorder="true"
              accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
              @init="handlePondInit"
              @addfile="handleAddImage"
              @removefile="handleRemoveImage"
            />

            <InputError :message="form.errors.images" />
          </div>

        </div>

      </form>

    </section>

  </article>

</template>

When I am updating the project, while I have managed to make the files display in the Filpond component, the update request hangs up, with a 500 server-error. If I comment out the Filepond code and perform a patch request, everything works just fine. What could I be missing?
The following is my web route file:
Route::group(['prefix' => 'projects'], function () {

    Route::get(
      '/',
      [\App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController::class, 'listing'],
    )->name('auth.projects.index');

    Route::get(
      '/c/{customer:cid?}',
      [\App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController::class, 'create'],
    )->name('auth.projects.create');

    Route::post(
      '/s',
      [\App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController::class, 'store'],
    )->name('auth.projects.store');

    Route::get(
      '/e/{project:pid}',
      [\App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController::class, 'edit'],
    )->name('auth.projects.edit');

    Route::get(
      '/i/{project:pid}',
      [\App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController::class, 'detail'],
    )->name('auth.projects.detail');

    Route::put(
      '/u/{project:pid}',
      [\App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController::class, 'update'],
    )->name('auth.projects.update');

    Route::delete(
      '/d/{project}/{image?}',
      [\App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController::class, 'destroy'],
    )->name('auth.projects.destroy');

  });

I need to upload the files together with the form, not separately. I am using Spartie's Laravel Media Library to handle file associations in the backend:
public function update(Request $request, Project $project)
{
    $customer = Customer::where('cid', $request->customer_id)->first();
    $request->merge(['customer_id' => $customer->id]);

    $validated = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'production' => 'required|date',
        'customer_id' => 'required|exists:customers,id',
        'description' => 'nullable|string',
        'images.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    // Update project details
    $project->update([
        'name' => $validated['name'],
        'production' => $validated['production'],
        'customer_id' => $customer->id,
        'description' => $validated['description'] ?? null,
    ]);

    // Handle image removals
    $existingMedia = $project->getMedia('bucket');
    $existingMediaUuids = $existingMedia->pluck('uuid')->toArray();
    $requestImageUuids = array_map(fn($image) => $image['uuid'], $request->input('images', []));

    // Delete images that are not present in the request
    foreach ($existingMedia as $media) {
        if (!in_array($media->uuid, $requestImageUuids)) {
            $media->delete();
        }
    }

    // Add new images
    if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
        foreach ($request->file('images') as $image) {
            // Check if the image is already present by its filename
            $fileName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $existingFileNames = $existingMedia->pluck('file_name')->toArray();

            // If the image file name is not in the existing list, upload it
            if (!in_array($fileName, $existingFileNames)) {
                $project->addMedia($image)->toMediaCollection('bucket');
            }
        }
    }

    return redirect()->route('auth.projects.index')->with('notify', [
        'type' => 'success',
        'title' => 'Project updated',
        'message' => 'Project has been successfully updated!',
    ]);
}

I tried removing the Filepond component and all the code related to it, then the request gets executed as expected. If I put Filepond code back, the issue happens again. This happens only when I am trying to update the project object. It works perfectly fine when I am creating the project object.

Do you have more information about the 500 error ? Do you have some error in storage/logs ? or in Apache (or Nginx) logs, it can be a server configuration error, not only in your code. Just to be sure, can you explicitly show us what "Filepond component" do you comment, is it "FilePondInput" ?
